# Where does Android store the platform, shared, media and release keys in the final Android OS image

Tags: android, code-signing

Does anyone have any idea where the public keys used for signing (platform, shared, media and release key ) stored in the final generated Android OS image?

The 'Signing Builds for Release' ( https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds ) page provides information on how Android OS images are signed.

The standard Android build uses four keys, all of which reside in build/target/product/security:

testkey: Generic default key for packages that do not otherwise specify a key. Used for development builds

releasekey: Generic default key for packages that do not otherwise specify a key.Used for release builds

platform: Test key for packages that are part of the core platform.

shared: test key for things that are shared in the home/contacts process.

media: Test key for packages that are part of the media/download system.

The public keys (releasekey.x509.pem, platform.x509.pem, shared.x509.pem, media.x509.pem) associated with the above private keys need to be included as part of the Android image.
These are provided as part of the build process and generally stored in build/target/product/security on the host used to build the Android OS image
However, what is not provided is where the public keys used for signing are located in the generated OS image.

For example when dm-verity is used, the RSA-2048 key in libmincrypt-compatible format is stored in the /boot partition at /verity_key.

Answer (score 1):

They are not stored directly, but are stored as part of signed apk which are already part of system image. PackageManager parses them and store them in
**/data/system/packages.xml**.

In that xml you see tags like:
public-key identifier

Which contains public key of all apks.
In case you already have some apk which is also on device, you can unzip it.

// To get public key from apk

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -print_certs -out cert.pem -in CERT.RSA
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -pubkey -noout
```

This will be same as one of public keys stored in packages.xml

Apart from this in device at **/etc/security/mac_permissions.xml** there are signatures which tell that app with certain signature below to certain SE context.
You can read its details at
http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/system/sepolicy/README

OTA certificates are stored at **/etc/security/otacerts.zip** which is used by recovery system.

Comment: what if you use RSA 4096 to create the keys? would that be supported?